# Git: without affecting remote, change directory structure (ignore parent directory)

Tags: git

If you get a project like this when you clone it:

```
--site name
  -- framework name
    --data (this is what I want as my root folder)
    --vagrant
    -- (other unimportant files)
```

I want to use my own vagrant box so I want just the contents of data folder to be in my root.

Is there a way to do it without replicating the folder structure and changing my nginx to point to `site/framework/data`? I imagine this is a common task..

Comment: No, you can’t. Not without actually making changes to the repository contents.

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mind is that if the repo is not your, fork it, clone and remove all directories but `data`. I you want to keep `data` up to date with the original repo you can always add the original repo as a remote and pull from there.

Comment: You can use the assume-unchanged if it will suit your need. its allowing you to modify files but telling git to ignore your changes and not to track those changes.

Comment: @CodeWizard, interesting. I didn't know that command.

Comment: `I want to use my own vagrant box so I want just the contents of data folder to be in my root.` - what is the relevance of vagrant and nginx usage to your question?

Comment: @AD7six wanted to explain why I want to ignore those extra folders

Comment: @CodeWizard assume-unchanged seems to do the job pretty well. thanks

Comment: This reads like an [x/y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem); you essentially want a different vagrant setup (having a different /vagrant root is how I read your comments) and are trying to do that with git - instead of simply changing your vagrant setup (by e.g. modifying the /vagrant share, or creating `data/Vagrantfile` and launching vagrant from there). In any event the question is not clear to me and does not sound common.